# Any good zerg double extractor trick builds for use against zerg?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

What is a good Zerg build that utilizes a double extradtor trick, yet allows for an effective economic advantage against zerg?

Comment: havent seen to many double extractor strats for zerg, well unless they go straight to mutalisk/baneling destruction. I wouldnt suggest going double extractor against another zerg player unless they are doing the same.

Comment: Mass voidray. Always. Mass. Voidray.

Answer (score 3):

The most noteworthy build is the 10 pool or well a modified version of it.
The basic build is:

- 10 Spawning Pool
- 11/10 Drone
- 12/10 Drone
- 12/10 Overlord (as soon as enough resources are available)
- 12/18 - Lings

This is a variation of the [10pool build](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/10_Pool).